# Valid characters for ChatGPT prompt?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

With following request payload (generated from `JSON.stringify(data)` without error):

```json
{
  "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  "messages": [
    { "role": "user", "content": "convert 4000 m² into acres." }
  ]
}
```

I got following ChatGPT API error response:

```
invalid_request_error: We could not parse the JSON body of your request. 
(HINT: This likely means you aren't using your HTTP library correctly. 
The OpenAI API expects a JSON payload, but what was sent was not valid JSON. 
If you have trouble figuring out how to fix this, please send an email to support@openai.com 
and include any relevant code you'd like help with.)
```

Changing `m²` to `square meters` solved the problem.

But I couldn't find any restrictions on characters in OpenAI documentation.

So which characters are valid for ChatGPT API, which are not?

For those restricted characters, how to escape/encode them?

Or, should I just filter out those characters?

**Edit:**

Now I'm pretty sure it's encoding problem. Any non-ascii characters will result in the same error, e.g. some Chinese characters:

```json
{
  "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  "messages": [{ "role": "user", "content": "一年有多少天" }]
}
```

**Edit 2:**

The code is a AWS Lambda function and runtime is Node.js 14.x.
The payload looks correct from logs. Here's the code:

```js
const https = require('https');

function apiRequest(data, apiKey) {
    let requestBody = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log('payload:', requestBody);
    const options = {
        hostname: 'api.openai.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/v1/chat/completions',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
            'Content-Length': requestBody.length
        },
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
            res.setEncoding('utf-8');
            let responseBody = '';

            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                responseBody += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
                console.log('response:', responseBody);
                resolve(JSON.parse(responseBody));
            });
        });

        req.on('error', (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });

        req.write(requestBody, 'utf-8');
        req.end();
    });
}
```

Comment: *"The OpenAI API expects a JSON payload, but what was sent was not valid JSON. 
If you have trouble figuring out how to fix this, please send an email to support@openai.com 
and include any relevant code you'd like help with."* - did you try that?...

Comment: Well that's not valid json at all. The `content` key needs to be quoted: `"content"`

Comment: Hopefully you're not building the payload manually? JSON should be created with a proper JSON library that's guaranteed to create valid JSON and escape whatever characters need escaping.

Comment: @0stone0 It was quoted. I forgot to add quotation marks when posting this answer.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I was generated from JavaScript object using JSON.stringify().

Comment: The API accepts that payload just fine when I try it.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue but I want to continue using "https" module. I wonder what else I can try.

Answer (score 0):

Changed runtime to Node.js 18.x and replaced `https` with `node-fetch`, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to convert the body to a Buffer before calling `req.write`, like so:

```
let requestBody = JSON.stringify(data);
requestBody= Buffer.from(requestBody , 'utf-8');
req.write(requestBody);
```